# Choosing a convergent subsequence to show sequential compactness

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $l^\infty$ be the set of bounded sequences. Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a function such that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(n) = 0$.

I want to show the set $A = \{x \in l^\infty : |x_n| \leq f(n) $ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is sequentially compact.

For an arbitrary sequence $(x^j \in A)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$, we know that $|x_n^j| \leq f(n)$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am guessing a convergent subsequence might converge to the sequence of all zeros, but I am not able to construct such a convergent subsequence.

Comment: It won't be sequentially compact, as written. Are you sure that $|x_n| < f(n)$, instead of $|x_n| \le f(n)$?

Comment: It is $|x_n| \leq f(n)$. That was a mistake.

Comment: I actually had an answer that I was working on, but what stopped me from completing it was actually notation. I think it's easier to do with (topological) compactness. I don't have time at the present moment to write such an answer up, but would you be interested in such an answer?

Comment: yes I am interested. In fact, you can write on weekend or anytime later (if you are willing ), it will still be of help.